# Setting inline URL with Jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, dynamic, anchor

I am using the following code to show social icons on hover: You can see the site here: http://vitaminjdesign.com/adrian/

```
$('a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
          if (event.type == 'mouseover') {

            $('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=(this)" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.gif" class="facebook" alt="facebook"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.gif" class="twitter" alt="twitter"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
          } else {
            $('a').find('.facebook,.twitter').stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
          }
        });
```

The problem I am having is within the facebook URL where you see (this). I want to dynamically add in the URL of the link associated with the current `a` being hovered. Basically, I want to add in the URL of the element being hovered on into the (this) area of the URL. Anyone?

Comment: Btw, it should be `target="_blank"` if you want each link to open in a _new_ window and not just a new one that'll be named `blank` and each subsequent link you click will open it that window instead of a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little nicer way (in my opinion) to create elements is to use the properties object argument.

Also, I assume you only want to load the new elements once, then just fade them thereafter.

```
$('.rssRow').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
      var twitFace = $(this).find('.facebook,.twitter');
      if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            if( twitFace.length ) {
                twitFace.fadeIn(500);
            } else { 
                loadTwitFace.call(this);
            }
      } else {
            twitFace.stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
      }
 });

function loadTwitFace() {

    $('<a>', { href:'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="' + $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '"',
             target:"blank"})
        .append($('<img>',{       src:'images/facebook.gif',
                            className:'facebook',
                                  alt:'facebook'}))
        .appendTo(this)
        .fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt function as well.....It blinks and doesnt enable a solid hover

Comment: @JCHASE11: Somehow I didn't notice that you were doing it on `hover`. Do you really want to add a new duplicate `<img>` every time you hover? Seems like you should do it *once*, then just do a `fadeIn/Out` after that.

Comment: You are correct, that is probably not the best way of doing it, but I am not familiar with your method...If you can rewrite the code so it works with my hover, Id gladly accept

Comment: @JCHASE: I just updated. Now each `<a>` will only append new elements if they're not currently there. Give it a shot and let me know how it went.

Comment: @JCHASE11: Yeah...hovering over the links by The Vancouver Sun creates some pretty funky effects.

Comment: check out your changes live. What do you think? I am not seeing the .stop() working and also I am getting a single facebook image when I hover just over fb

Comment: @JCHASE11: I'll do an update. Basically change the event to `mouseenter mouseleave`, and assign the hover to the `.rssRow` instead (as long as it fits in with your intention). It seems to work better that way when I test your page.

Comment: ...also, I see you're using jQuery 1.4.2. Just be aware that in that version the `mouseenter` event is reported as `mouseover`. If you upgrade, it will be reported as `mouseenter`. Important for your `if()` statement.

Comment: Gotcha thanks so much! There still seems to be a small problem with the URL itself. It says undefined....It works with the below methods. Im sure its just a small fix in the jquery

Comment: I updated my jquery to 1.4.4 and the code doesnt work at all.... I uploaded it for you to see....NEVERMIND THIS COMMENT.

Comment: @JCHASE11: Sorry, we need to update the `loadTwitFace` method to find the `<a>` and get the `href`. So change `this.href` to `$(this).find('a').attr('href')`

Comment: @JCHASE11: ...actually, I need a little clarification at this point. Where exactly should the new `<a>` elements go?

Comment: @JCHASE11: Looks like you've got it figured out. Glad I could help. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' 
    + $(this).attr("href") + ' target="blank">
```

Comment: you're missing a trailing double-quote after the `href=""`